# exit from ipython

Tags: python, interpreter, ipython

I like IPython a lot for working with the python interpreter. However, I continually find myself typing `exit` to exit, and get prompted "Type exit() to exit."

I know I can type Ctrl-D to exit, but is there a way I can type `exit` without parentheses and get IPython to exit?

**Update**: Thanks to [nosklo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17160/nosklo), this can be easily done by adding the following line to the main() function in your `ipy_user_conf.py`:

```
# type exit to exit
ip.ex("type(exit).__repr__ = lambda s: setattr(s.shell, 'exit_now', True) or ''")
```

Comment: I also have (had) your problems using 'exit' because of the same muscle memory.  For anyone new to IPython (or looking for a quicker way), hitting <ctrl>-D twice is faster.  Just don't hit it three times or you'll be logged out of your (linux) shell as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
>>> import sys
>>> class Quitter(object):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         sys.exit()
... 
>>> exit = Quitter()
```

You can use it like this:

```
>>> exit
```

**EDIT:**

I dont use `ipython` myself, but it seems to have some wierd `sys.exit` handler.
The solution I found is as follows:

```
In [1]: type(exit).__repr__ = lambda s: setattr(s.shell, 'exit_now', True) or ''
```

Usage:

```
In [2]: exit
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work with IPython. It has its own Quitter class which calls the appropriate exit method on the actual IPShell instance. But the general idea is correct.

Comment: @Robert Kern: Okay, found an `ipython` solution.

Answer (score 5):

`%exit`, or `%Exit`, if you have confirmation enabled and want to skip it.
You can alias it to e.g. `%e` by putting `execute __IPYTHON__.magic_e = __IPYTHON__.magic_exit` in your ipythonrc.

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to literally type "exit". Because it is stuck in muscle memory.

Comment: `%exit` or `%Exit` are no line magic functions under IPython version 1.1.0. So using IPython 1.1.0 this answer does not work for me at all.

Comment: @halloleo My heart bleeds for you on the account of answer from 5 years ago no longer being relevant. `exit` works OOB on recent IPython versions and this entire question is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

With iPython 6.2.1, you can simply type `exit` to exit the interpreter:

```
$ ipython
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
In [1]: exit
$
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in IPython 0.10, you should be able to set **IPYTHON**.rc.confirm_exit = False

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, I find myself constantly using ctrl-d to exit from every type REPL interface, including ipython. There is need to type exit/logout almost always.