# ipython shell - how to emulate an enter press

Tags: python, ipython, key-bindings

I would like to exit the ipython shell, i.e. type %exit then hit enter, when the escape key is pressed. I can successfully type "%escape" in the shell, but am having difficulty figuring out the "enter" press.

ref: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config/details.html#keyboard-shortcuts

Code in a .py file in the startup folder:

```py
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding import KeyBindings
from IPython import get_ipython
ip = get_ipython()

def exit_ipy(event):
    buffer = event.current_buffer
    buffer.insert_text('%exit') # just need to figure out how to insert an "enter" press after
    buffer.accept_action.validate_and_handle(event.cli, buffer) # I thoght this may work?

ip = get_ipython()
registry = ip.pt_app.key_bindings
registry.add_binding(u'escape')(exit_ipy)
```

Comment: Silly comment: Did you try adding a '\n' after '%exit'? Like, `buffer.insert_text('%exit\n')`.

Comment: I did, that produces a line break. Also tried `\r`.

Comment: the question is, where do you want the control flow to exit to? Exit out the entire Python interpreter? Return to the script execution at some point? You can do both in the exit even handler (e.g. just call `sys.exit()`)

Comment: @JerieWang I would like "%exit" typed followed by enter; I was debugging, I would want to exit the debugger on the first escape press, for example

Comment: Would one of [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527689/exit-from-ipython) work? Just trying to answer the question behind the question here. :) 

i.e. One suggestion is to turn off exit confirmation: `IPYTHON.rc.confirm_exit = False`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick :

```
import pyautogui
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding import KeyBindings
from IPython import get_ipython
ip = get_ipython()

def exit_ipy(event):
    buffer = event.current_buffer
    buffer.insert_text('%exit') 
    pyautogui.press('enter') # simulates an enter press
   
ip = get_ipython()
registry = ip.pt_app.key_bindings
registry.add_binding(u'escape')(exit_ipy)
```

`pyautogui` let you simulate a key press exactly like if you did it yourself, so I think that this solution will work
PS: **I CAN NOT TEST THIS SO I DID NOT**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use `pyautogui`. Interestingly, a new line is formed--equivalent to entering `%exit\n`, rather than the keystrokes be submitted.

Comment: That's definitely weird, but as I said i can't test this because I don't have IPython set up